# Issue with credentials for private repo and oidc.azuread.clientSecret in Helm ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, argocd

I'd like to deploy ArgoCD using helm and include credentials for my private repo as long as $oidc.azuread.clientSecret for the SSO integration.

My questions are:

1- Do I need to create manually a secrert called "argocd-secret" to include the secret for $oidc.azuread.clientSecret ?

2- How can I include the username and personal token from Azure to get access to my private repo in Azure Git? If not possible with personal token how can I do that with SSH keys using the helm values?

https://github.com/kurtburak/argocd/blob/main/argocd-install/argo-cd/values.yaml

I think this is the interesing part from the argocd helm chart:

```
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
    # repositories: |
    #   - url: git@github.com:group/repo.git
    #     sshPrivateKeySecret:
    #       name: secret-name
    #       key: sshPrivateKey
    #   - type: helm
    #     url: https://charts.helm.sh/stable
    #     name: stable
    #   - type: helm
    #     url: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
    #     name: argo
    # oidc.config: |
    #   name: AzureAD
    #   issuer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/v2.0
    #   clientID: CLIENT_ID
    #   clientSecret: $oidc.azuread.clientSecret
    #   requestedIDTokenClaims:
    #     groups:
    #       essential: true
    #   requestedScopes:
    #     - openid
    #     - profile
    #     - email
```

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Devops added on tags.

Comment: Adding the `devops` tag does not result in the question being visible on [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Anyway, that's not a devops related question. It's a HELM related question and how to pass the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with the first problem myself, and seeing as no one has replied to you;

1. You need to create an extra secret when deploying the helm chart, this can be done in the values.yaml or with parameter `--set "configs.secret.extra.oidc\.azure\.clientSecret=$argosecret"` (where $argosecret preferably is a secret variable passed from e.g. your CD). This will create `oidc.azure.clientSecret` in the secret `argocd-secret`.